# Automate builds for custom RaspberryPi images

Tags: raspbian, sd-card, version-control

I have a Python application that is used exclusively on RaspberryPi’s (RPi 2/3/zero) due to its GPIOs and other hardware interfaces. I would like to automate the build of finished SD card images based on Raspbian so that I and new users can quickly deploy the changes.

There are [several](https://github.com/b-s101/build-raspberrypi-image) [options](https://github.com/TheSin-/rpi-img-builder) [out there](https://github.com/andrius/build-raspbian-image) and I would like to ask which ones can be recommended to be used. Metrics that are important include:

- Ease of use
- Integration into automated build systems and version control
- Size of community
- Difficulty of integrating custom software
- Customizability of final image (users, ssh keys, installed packages)

Comment: To add to the other options already given you may want to look at puppet, chef, resin.io, creating a shell script to pull your custom code from github, building a package .dpkg of your code and adding your package repo to the Pi's sources list so your code is installed like any other package.

Comment: Well said, Steve.  I agree they are all suitable alternatives that can be recommended.

Answer (score 1):

I would investigate Ansible.  "Ansible delivers simple IT automation that ends repetitive tasks and frees up DevOps teams for more strategic work." ([Ansible Website](https://www.ansible.com/)).

While it is used extensively to manage infrastructure, it can also be used to manage (automate) development processes and meta-infrastructure.  You create the model of your ideal development and deployment processes via roles and playbooks, add variables to templates, package and deliver your image.  Then it is all about providing the customer/client with the content and playbooks to be run from their control machine in their infrastructure environment.

**Ease of use** is subjective; therefore, I venture the following.  The files Ansible uses to control behaviour are YAML based.  YAML is easily understandable by both technical and administrative staff making the ramp to organizational fluency cost effective.

**Integration** with other systems is one of Ansible's strong points. There are hundreds of modules that come ready to use out of the box.  You can customize any module, derive new functionality, or develop your own modules that specifically meet the needs of your team and/or the requirements of your customer.

**Size of community** is again a strong point for Ansible.  It is a well supported open source product surrounded and uplifted by commercial tools.  Some well respected companies are invested in Ansible's support.  You determine the appropriate level of product engagement and you can be assured there is a robust community ready to help (see for yourself in the devops, unix, server fault and stack overflow SE communities).

**Difficulty of integrating custom software** is similar to **Ease of use** in that it is subjective (but also relative to demand).  I posit that a tools ability to scale in capability comes at the cost of complexity.  The more you demand from Ansible, the more it will surprise you with capability; however, you will have moments where you don't know what you don't know followed by epiphanous joy as you discover yet another solution under the hood.

**Customizability** is Ansible's bailiwick.  You can use what ever tools you prefer to do the dirty work and have Ansible manage the flow from process to process (avoiding inter-process fumbles often associated with manual hand-offs).

There are other DevOps support tools, I believe Ansible is well worth your time to investigate.  I don't wish to drone on about it's features and capability when their website is far better and delivering the level of information you need.

Comment: Thanks for the extensive answer, but it is too generic to be useful. It would also be applicable to “What is a good CI/CD solution for Flask applications”. Providing an example playbook that generates custom Raspbian images would be useful

Comment: You asked: "I would like to ask which ones can be recommended to be used."  You received answers and a robust comment to that question.  If I had known you just wanted to eat fish, I wouldn't have bothered showing you where to fish.  Refine your question to better reflect your expectation.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.pibakery.org/

Is what I am currently trying to use. I haven't actually made it work yet as I just got my pi zero today to try it out with.

- Ease of use - almost too easy
- Integration - it makes an xml file which can be managed by basically anything.

The rest Im not sure about as I said I just got my pi today and only plan on getting my project off the ground in a few weeks.

Comment: Any experience with chaining pibakery to your CI?

Comment: If you are still looking I switched over to this: http://dietpi.com/# Sorry for the late response but I just started a new job.